# Amount of people in each job U.S

Tags: data-request

I am looking for something that will tell me how many people are employed in each occupation in the United States. E.g. 20 million people in education, 12 million people working in the food industry, etc. It can be specific like the amount of teachers, or more broad such as education industry, food industry, automobile industry etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for data from the Bureau of Labor Statistics. Probably the [Current Employment Statistics](http://www.bls.gov/web/empsit/ceseeb1a.htm), which provide a breakdown of all employees by [NAICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Industry_Classification_System) industry/sector.